# Is there a service that will check redirection for an e-business

Tags: security, service, web-crawler

Like a lot of businesses my employer is dealing with the new world of PCI compliance by avoiding the hard stuff and redirecting our customers to a third-party payment service. The process will entail the customer entering order details into our system but then being redirected to the merchant bank's payment service for the entry of those all important card details.

We wish to retain the services of some business that periodically fills in stages 1 and 2 of our order form with some dummy data, presses place order and sees that the URL it ends up at is in fact the one we're expecting, a bit like a bot or a web spider.

If it finds we've been clickjacked it would alert us by text message or twitter feed or whatever the cool kids are using these days.

Does anyone know of a service that performs this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still in the process of going through some suggestions and hammering out what exactly we're going to do but almost all the info I've gained has come from:

http://www.softwareqatest.com/index.html

A devastatingly useful site which provides more than answers to this functional testing scenario. There are a couple of Web-Based services which execute QA Functional Testing scripts against your site and send alerts and reports if the tests fail.

The two I had a quick look at were http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/ and http://www.watchmouse.com/en/

The latter service uses [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) scripts in its tests so you can home brew them and then upload to their server for regular execution.

Answer (score 0):

No,  I don't believe that there is a service like this.  Usually companies with specific testing needs like this will use [QuickTest Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional).

Comment: Hmm, I continued my own research and believe I may have found a couple... I will let you know if they turn out to be the real deal I've only read sales flim flam so far.